# Add a number to each selection in Sublime Text 2, incremented once per selection

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to add insert a number that is incremented once per cursor in Sublime Text 2?

Example, with `|` as the cursor:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
vehicula sed, mauris nam eget| 
neque a pede nullam, ducimus adipiscing, 
vestibulum pellentesque pellentesque laoreet faucibus.|
```

Desired result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 1|
vehicula sed, mauris nam eget2| 
neque a pede nullam, ducimus adipiscing, 
vestibulum pellentesque pellentesque laoreet faucibus.3|
```

Does this functionality exist natively, or is there a plugin providing it?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

I recommend the plugin [Text Pastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry). The [Number Sequence command](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry/wiki/Examples#from-1-to-3) is the one you need.

I prefer to use the [Insert Nums command](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry/wiki/Examples#insert-nums-syntax):

> Text Pastry has a build in support for the Insert Nums syntax by
>   providing three numbers separated by one space:
>
> N M P
>
> N: the start index.
>
> M represents the step size which will be added to the index for
>   each selection.
>
> P must be > 0 and will be used to pad the index with
>   leading zeroes.

Comment: Ridiculously helpful.

Comment: Text Pastry : Multi-select :: Multi-select : Find & Replace

Comment: This plugin seems perfect for me. But I need to increment from 1 to 5 and repeat multiple times. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I found that I had to first select the lines and use Ctrl + Shift + L to select all affected lines, then use Text Pastry for numbering, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upEieoTwnjs

Comment: make a multi line selection (not only cursors) with the start number selected. Press ctrl + alt + T, it opens a nice menu which explaines the rest.

Comment: This solution works in Sublime Text 3 as well.  For me the primary issue was that you need to know how to open the Text Pastry command line (CTRL-ALT-N).  So, to get incrementing numbers from 01 to 10, select 10 lines (shift+right-click/drag the desired columns), press `CTRL-ALT-N`, then type `1 1 2`

Comment: Chucky: https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry/wiki/Number-Range explains how to do what you want. TL;DR: `range <start> <end>[ <step=1>[ <padding=1>]]`

Answer (score 110):

I think that the only way to achieve what you ask is to create your own plugin.

`Tools/New Plugin...`:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class IncrementSelectionCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        start_value = int(self.view.substr(self.view.sel()[0]))

        counter = 0
        for selection in self.view.sel():
            self.view.insert(edit, selection.begin(), str(start_value + counter))
            counter = counter + 1

        for selection in self.view.sel():
            self.view.erase(edit, selection)
```

Save it in your `User` directory.
Then add a shortcut to your `Key Bindings - User`:

```
{ "keys": ["YOUR_SHORTCUT"], "command": "increment_selection" }
```

Now you can place the cursors where you need:

[image]

Insert the number the counter should start from (in this case 1):

[image]

Select the number you typed (<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd><—</kbd>):

[image]

Type the shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, very helpful. I will do this as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I've attempted to make this plugin, but haven't been able to get it to work - placing multiple cursors, inserting `1` and pressing my hotkey does nothing. Is there something I need to to in order to activate new plugin?

Comment: Before pressing your hot keys, you have to select the text you entered, with shift+left arrow (look at the second to last screenshot in my text).

Comment: Yes I did do that. My hotkey is: `  { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+i"], "command": "increment_selection" }`, in Key Bindings - User. No output in ST2 console

Comment: I verified the code both on Mac and Windows, and it should work. 

Try to look at the console after you have typed the shortcut: maybe there is some error that could help to understand the problem (`View/Show Console`).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, and I did look @ the console, nothing. I will have another go in the morning.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I verified it on Ubuntu too, and it worked. I'm sorry, I don't know what can be wrong... Try to add a `print("something")` in the `run` method, to verify that the plugin is invoked by the shortcut.

Comment: I'm sure this does work but the plugin `Text Pastry` mentioned in a subsequent answer provides a solution that directly solves my original question - a plugin that provides this functionality.

Comment: Yes, `Text Pastry` is definitely a better solution!

Comment: I successfully used this today, though when i placed '1' as my selection number it failed with ' ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' '.  Works fine when entering 0 though.  Thanks!!

Comment: This should be mark as Answer. Excellent!! Thanks Working in SL3 too.

Comment: Great plugin! The only downside is that every integer in the selection needs to be of the exact same value.

Answer (score 25):

You want to had a number at each row that you have selected, but not the same. For exemple, you select 5 cursors and you want to write 1 2 3 4 5.

select your 5 cursors  [image] maybe you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>maj</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on the highlighted lines

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>maj</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select arithmetic
[image]

Because you have 5 cursors, it propose 1 2 3 4 5
[image]
[image]

If you want you can change your number of iteration
[image]

Or start from an other number than 1
[image]

Add odd number
[image]

Comment: This should be accepted answer. As it appears that Sublime supports this natively and no extra plugin is needed.