# How to insert a column of increasing numbers in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

```
text
text
text
text
```

after the editing, those text becomes to

```
1 text
2 text
3 text
4 text
```

It's easy in Notepad ++ with the Column Editor， but I don't know how to do the same in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Maybe this question can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574941/add-a-number-to-each-selection-in-sublime-text-2-incremented-once-per-selection

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question to which @RiccardoMarotti linked.

Comment: I recommend the plugin Text Pastry. I posted about it in the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14670627/776778)

Comment: Nice plugin! I've wrote a plugin based on @Riccardo Marotti's answer, https://github.com/yulanggong/IncrementSelection

Answer (score 134):

The *Text Pastry* plugin does the job very well. It offers the [Insert Numbers Syntax](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry/wiki/Examples#insert-nums-syntax).

Select multiple lines with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Sublime default):

```
   text|
   text|
   text|
   text|
```

Move the cursor where you want it:

```
 | text
 | text
 | text
 | text
```

And insert numbers with [Text Pastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry) by hitting <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (in **Windows**: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and entering <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>:

```
 1| text
 2| text
 3| text
 4| text
```

Where <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> stands for:

- Integer to start with <kbd>1</kbd>
- Increment by <kbd>1</kbd>
- Padd leading zeros <kbd>0</kbd>

Replace <kbd>CMD</kbd> with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> on Windows or Linux machines.

Comment: For me the Text Pastry input is a text box. When I saw [1][1][0] above I thought it means typing `110` which will not get your what you want. You need to enter is `1 1 0` with spaces. When using kbd tags you include spaces? Just wondering what's the visual difference between `110` and `1 1 0` if using kbd tags.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do kbd spaces. But you get the idea now? :)

Comment: The correct answer is below by @Nicoolasens. No need for plugins

Answer (score 108):

copy of this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/64083371/5902698

You want to have a number at each row that you selected, but not the same. For exemple, you select 5 cursors and you want to write 1 2 3 4 5.

select your 5 cursors (maybe you can use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)
[image]

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select arithmetic
[image]

Because you have 5 cursors, it propose 1 2 3 4 5
[image]
[image]

If you want you can change your step of iteration
[image]

Or start from an other number than 1
[image]

Add even numbers
[image]

Comment: This answer looks simple. Will be better to mention how to select multiple cursers. CTRL+ALT+UP/DOWN for windows. Thanks!

Comment: amazing - so happy I scrolled past all the plugin suggestions

Comment: @TintuThomas it doesn't work on my laptop, but I edit to mention the ctrl + shift + L to put multiple cursor on a selection of lines

Comment: I've been working with sublime text for a long time, and I've could've used this forever... thanks so much!

Comment: perfect answer, no plugin required

Comment: This is just brilliant! I have always hated having to install plugins to automate such trivial tasks... Interestingly, the number of steps involved is same as that by a plugin or even less in some cases, lol.

Comment: As bonus, I have upvoted the copy of this answer on the other post you linked. Cheers!

Answer (score 49):

For this particular case you can use **[Increment Selection](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Increment%20Selection)** package. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) while having multiple cursors at the beginning of each line.
In addition to [melinath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139119/5515843), here's an example of how to do it:

You will need [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) first. It shouldn't take more than 30 seconds to install both things.

Steps:

1. Install **Package Control**.

- Open Command Palette: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).
- Type `Install Package Control` and click to install.

1. Install **Increment Selection** package.

- Open Command Palette again.
- Type `Package Control: Install Package`, click on it and wait a short period.
- Type `Increment Selection` and click on it to install.

1. Add line numbers to the beginning of each line.

- Select all lines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Change selection to multiple lines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- Go to the start of each line by pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>)
- Use Increment Selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

Result:

[image: increment-selection.gif]

---

#### Other examples for *Increment Selection*

*Increment Selection* can also replace numbers, prefix numbers with leading zeroes, increment letters, increment by a step and more.

```
   [1] text    [1] text    [1] ->  1| text  2| text  3|
   [a] text    [a] text    [a] ->  a| text  b| text  c|
  [01] text   [01] text   [01] -> 01| text 02| text 03|
[05,3] text [05,3] text [05,3] -> 05| text 08| text 11|
[5,-1] text [5,-1] text [5,-1] ->  5| text  4| text  3|
```

Hint: `[]` stands for a selection, `|` stands for a caret.

#### Featured similar plugins

- [Selection Evaluator](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Selection%20Evaluator): Evaluate selected mathematical expression with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>).

Comment: FWIW this solution works in sublime text 3.2.2 build 3211 as well.  Total game changer no need to have a spreadsheet open just to produce a series of numbers.

Comment: you saved my hours. thumbs up

Answer (score 26):

The [IncrementSelection](https://github.com/yulanggong/IncrementSelection) plugin enables this behavior. If you have [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) installed, you can just search for and install it. Easy peasy!

Comment: I found this plugin to be quite excellent.  I was manually generating an SVG pattern and needed to increment several plot positions.  The plugin did the math and everything for me.   ```<path d="M330,0C220,63.7,0,191,0,191"/><path d="M330-2C220,61.7,0,189,0,189"/>
<path d="M330-_C220,__.7,0,___,0,___"/>```

Answer (score 3):

Use **Emmet** package try this :

```
  {$ text${newline}}*4
```

Comment: Very good! BTW, if you want to change the counter base value to 3 (e.g. 3, 4, 5, 6), replace the first `$` with `$@3`. If you want to reverse the counter (e.g. 4, 3, 2, 1), replace the first `$` with `$@-`. If you want to reverse the counter back to 3 (e.g. 6, 5, 4, 3), replace the first `$` with `$@-3`. If you want padding zeros (e.g. 001, 002, 003, 004), replace the first `$` with `$$$`. See https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#item-numbering

Comment: This came in handy!  `{$ => $,${newline}}*12` to create array with keys & values, months of the year

Answer (score 3):

My simple workaround (up until now when I found this thread) was to go to my spreadsheet editor generate the sequence there, copy, back to subl, expand the cursor over however many lines and paste.

This approach can be applied in any text editor that allows you to expand (clone) the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plugin ConyEdit to do this, use its command line `cc.abl '#1 '` to append before lines with the contents that you want.

Answer (score -1):

@Nicoolasens This answer is great! Just adding one detail: On macOS you can follow these steps to put a curser at the end of each line:

1. Use command+A to choose all lines;
2. Use command+shift+L to put a
   curser after each line.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31715570)