# Sublime text replace all lines first number in sequential order

Tags: sublimetext3

Modding for a game, and the first number in each line needs to be sequential order, had to delete some so there no longer in sequential order, How does one replace the numbers back in sequential order.

[image: image of CSV file]

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a column of increasing numbers in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640093/how-to-insert-a-column-of-increasing-numbers-in-sublime-text-2)